# Echo html with PHP (Slim Framework) issue

Tags: php, frameworks, echo, slim

[image: Echo html with PHP (Slim Framework) issue]

---

Output is

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

---

but I want..

## Hello world

---

How can I fix it? thank you

Comment: probably didn't output a text/html content-type header, so it's being rendered as text/plain, that or the html is being escaped, and your output is really `&lt;h1&gt;etc...` do a "view source" to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was only necessary to define the content-type

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
      $app->contentType('text/html');
      echo "<h1>Hello world</h1>";
});
```

---

[*thank marc-b*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595204/echo-html-with-php-slim-framework-issue/32603057#comment53044037_32595204)